# Simultaneously use front and rear PC audio jacks

Tags: sound-card

I'm running Windows7 HP on an optiplex 755.(on-board sound card) Is there a work around or some drivers I can get so that it doesn't shut off the rear output if I plug into the front one?

Comment: This is a site for professional sound design (or hobbyists engaging in the audio production side of sound design.  This appears to be about consumer products and sound and is off-topic.  Try SuperUser for such questions.

Answer (score 0):

It solely depends on the sound card's manufacturer - you need there software (driver and some utility) to perform that.